# Laravel Eloquent accessing a 3rd relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 4 models, User, Profile, Audit and AuditApplications.

My table structure looks something like:

```
User
    - id
    - ... other user-related fields

Profile
    - id
    - user_id
    - ... various profile fields

Audit
    - id
    - user_id

AuditApplications
    - id
    - audit_id
    - user_id
```

My User model looks like this:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Profile');
}

public function auditApplications()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AuditApplications');
}
```

So I can get the user and their related profile easily and also a list of audits a user has applied for.

Next, I have AuditApplications table which holds a list of user IDs and audit ids of users that have applied to an audit. My AuditApplications table has the following relationship.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

So I can return a list of users that have applied to an audit like so:

```
$applicants = AuditApplications::where('audit_id', $audit->id)->with('user')->get();
```

All this works well as expected but now I want to access the user's profile when I get a list of applications. The relationship is a distance one so I want to get a list of users and their profiles in the AuditApplications model.

Is there a way of doing this in Eloquent without creating a loop in my controller to then loop over each of the users getting their profiles individually?

Comment: many users can apply to an audit??auditapplications is pivot table then i guess. to access anything from profile table use `auditapplication->user->profile->profile_attribute` and you can eager load the relationships too like `->with('user','user.profile')`

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes I believe that is the correct relationship. When an audit is created many users can ask to join it. Okay thank you I will look into your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do `->with('user.profile')`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25673060)

Comment: i disagree, this is eager loading: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading